# Escaping end of quotation Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, quoting

In my stored procedures, I'd normally go like execute immediate q'[code to execute].
However, I have something in my code which has '$[*]'. The quote and bracket is interpreted by Oracle as the end of my quote. How can I escape this? Please find below full code.

```
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_err_text AS
    WITH aux AS (
        SELECT
            err_txt
        FROM
            u339990_mr2
        WHERE
            err_txt IS NOT NULL
    )
    SELECT
        error_text,
        COUNT(*) AS ct,
        round(RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(1)) OVER() * 100, 2) perc
    FROM
        aux CROSS APPLY
            JSON_TABLE(err_txt, '$[*]'
                COLUMNS
                    error_text PATH '$'
            )
    GROUP BY
        error_text
    ORDER BY
        ct DESC,
        error_text
        ]'
    ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a different character (or characters) for the `q` quotation syntax.

`q'[ ... ]'` is correct, but you can also use `q'( ... )'` (or the same with curly braces or `<` and `>`). Also, you can use any single character (not paired) as in `q'@ ... @'` or `q'^ ... ^'` - just use a character where the closing combination doesn't naturally arise in your data. This is exactly why the syntax allows this flexibility.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617

Answer (score 3):

you can use any character with the q-quote syntax, it doesn't have to be square brackets. Check this code:

```
set serveroutput on size 999999
clear screen
declare
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(q'[some text with  'quotes']');
  dbms_output.put_line(q'!some text with square [] brackets!');
  dbms_output.put_line(q'€some text with square [] brackets and exclamation marks ! €');
  dbms_output.put_line(q'~some text with square [] brackets, exclamation marks ! and a €~');
  dbms_output.put_line(q'zsome text with square [] brackets, exclamation marks ! and a ~ z');
  
end;
/
```