# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol in DBMS_SCHEDULER

Tags: oracle, plsql

Calling the package inside the job gives an Error report -

```
ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "
  );
end; : AUXSQLDBIND4: = SqlDevBind1Z_1; : AUXSQLDBIND3: = SqlDevBind1Z_2; : AUXSQLDBIND2: = SqlDevBind1Z_3; : AUXSQLDBIND1: = SqlDevBind "
```

Help call the packet with the passed variable work_date for a certain calculation for each day of the month.

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
job_name => 'J_ACCOUNT_TURNOVER_F',
job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP, enabled => TRUE,
job_action => 
'declare
start_date number;
end_date number;
work_date date;
begin
start_date := to_number(to_char(to_date('2018-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'j'));
end_date := to_number(to_char(to_date('2018-01-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'j'));
for cur_r in start_date..end_date loop
 work_date := to_char(to_date(cur_r, 'j'), 'yyyyMMdd');
 dma.fill_account_turnover_f.fill(work_date);
end loop;
end;'
);
end;
```

Comment: SQL Developer's GUI for dbms_scheduler will let you click and type through this and at the end if will give you the entire PL/SQL block you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be simpler if you created a stored procedure and called it, instead of embedding that anonymous PL/SQL block into `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB` call? Now you have to **escape** single quotes, i.e. use two consecutive ones every time. Something like this:

```
begin
DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
job_name => 'J_ACCOUNT_TURNOVER_F',
job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP, enabled => TRUE,
job_action => 
'declare
start_date number;
end_date number;
work_date date;
begin
start_date := to_number(to_char(to_date(''2018-01-01'', ''yyyy-MM-dd''), ''j''));
end_date := to_number(to_char(to_date(''2018-01-31'', ''yyyy-MM-dd''), ''j''));
for cur_r in start_date..end_date loop
 work_date := to_char(to_date(cur_r, ''j''), ''yyyyMMdd'');
 dma.fill_account_turnover_f.fill(work_date);
end loop;
end;'
);
end;
/
```

Comment: It was interesting to solve without calling procedures. Thanks for the help. You solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're allergic to stored procedures :) Here is how you can do it without having to escape each individual quote. It is called the "Q Quote syntax".

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
job_name => 'J_ACCOUNT_TURNOVER_F',
job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP, enabled => TRUE,
job_action => 
q'!declare
start_date number;
end_date number;
work_date date;
begin
start_date := to_number(to_char(to_date('2018-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'j'));
end_date := to_number(to_char(to_date('2018-01-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'j'));
for cur_r in start_date..end_date loop
 work_date := to_char(to_date(cur_r, 'j'), 'yyyyMMdd');
 dma.fill_account_turnover_f.fill(work_date);
end loop;
end;'
);
end;!'
```

More examples in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66464863/escaping-end-of-quotation-oracle-sql/66465225) question